# Concepts in scheme theory that work just as well in locally ringed spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, big-list

As a student learning scheme theory with a broader background in differential and complex geometry, I always find it useful to discover "constructions" of schemes which work just as well in the setting of locally ringed spaces (and so I can see how they work in manifolds). For example, the Zariski tangent space and open / closed immersions work just as well in general locally ringed spaces.

What are some other constructions / definitions that one would learn in a course of scheme theory that work as well in the more general setting of locally ringed spaces? I am also interested if you think that it would be useful to learn them in that context or if it would be detrimental. (Perhaps the notion you have in mind works beautifully in the context of schemes but doesn't work very well in ringed spaces.)

Comment: I don't think the Zariski (co)tangent space works well for general locally ringed spaces. The definition can be interpreted, of course, but I seem to recall it gives the wrong answer for $C^k$-manifolds ($k < \infty$).

Comment: I suppose you would want to consider properties that are phrased purely in terms of open sets and the structure sheaf, as opposed to properties that somehow make use of the existence of a ring whose spectrum is the given open set.

Comment: @ZhenLin really? Why is that?

Comment: @TabesBridges sure! Do you know some cases of that other than the ones that I've talked about?

Comment: An example of concept which also works in the locally ringed spaces : line bundles/Picard group and $\check {H^1}(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*)$. Is this the kind of example you are looking for ?

Comment: @Roland surely they are an example!